# jquery datepicker gets hidden inside footer

Tags: jquery, html

I am using jquery datepicker. In a page I have a footer, when the datepicker pops up it gets hidden inside the footer. How can I fix this bug?
Here is my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8devrvv8/7/)

```
Here I have tried with footer and datepicker. But the date is hidden.
```

Comment: Just set Z-index to 9999 like this {.ui-select .ui-btn select{z-index:9999 !important
                          
                          }

Comment: @Anurag_Systematix it is not working for me!

Comment: Or set the Z-index of your footer to 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

Put footer's `z-index:0` and `background-color` of `tbody` (calendar) to white.

**HTML:**

```
<div data-role='footer' data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" data-hide-during-focus="" 
style='padding:40px;background-color:red;z-index:0'> 
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.ui-datepicker-calendar tbody {background-color:#FFF;}
```

Here is the [Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8devrvv8/12/)

Comment: @sharon: Glad that it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your footer's `z-index` is higher that the date popup

that is why footer is on top of your date popup.

Set your footer's `z-index to 0 or less that the date popup` and it will work.

**Updated Fiddle** https://jsfiddle.net/8devrvv8/8/

Answer (score 0):

**From the documentation ([here](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#inline)):** call .datepicker() on a div instead of an input to show by default.

**Updated fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/8devrvv8/13/

I deleted the form and input, and replaced it with a div:

```
<div id="beautiful-calendar"></div>
```

called .datepicker() on aforementioned div in Javascript:

```
$('#beautiful-calendar').datepicker()
```